Interest v. Right
How does interest differ from right? Please differentiate their meanings?

9 With respect, this is why it was questionable for French CJ to suggest that it is possible
to create a trust in which ‘there was no equitable interest in its assets held by anyone’:
Kennon v Spry [2008] HCA 56, 238 CLR 366 [49]; although much depends on what he
meant by an ‘equitable interest’. If an equitable interest is that which is held by a person
who has a right (albeit possibly defeasible, and possibly only as a member of a group) to
some of the trust property, then it is not possible. An attempt to do that leads (unless it
creates a charitable trust) to an immediate resulting trust, so that the settlor holds an
equitable interest.†

It's regrettably ironic that Smith didn't differentiate, when he acknowledged on page 18

There is no rule book for the terminology of trusts, and indeed some of it
is surprisingly unstable. Some of the most basic words and phrases—‘trust’, ‘beneficiary’, ‘discretionary trust’—are ambiguous. This ambiguity
can lead to serious misunderstandings about fundamental principles.†

† Lionel Smith, “Massively Discretionary Trusts” (2017) 70:1 Current Legal Problems 1, page 20.

@Jen please peruse both questions to see the differences yourself. first, the contexts differ. that question deals with land law. don't you see the tag "[tag:real-estate]"? But I am asking about trusts here. again, don't you see the tag "[tag:trusts-and-estates]"? second, ohwilleke never answered that other linked question on interest vs. right. he just cited a definition of right, then claimed "there is no context" to the question without contrasting estate, interest, title.
